# Is need install mysql on AWS EC2 if i am using AWS rds as database instance?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have trying to configure  AWS server myself.

Using

**Info1:**`EC2 as hosting and select Ubuntu 14 as OS and install Apache PHP and i have check that it php and http works.`
 I have install Apache and php using below commend

```
sudo apt-get install apche2 php5 libapche2-mod-php5
```

**Info2:** `Rds as mysql database instance.` it is working

Now i have  put a `ambc.sql on ec2 system` and trying`import it to MySQL-rds system`

Please the screen shot:

```
Issue1:
```

**when we trying to import sql from  EC2 it show   error The Program 'mysql' can be ..**.see the screen shot

[image]

**Issue2:** `is need to install some MySQL or PHP to library which will connect EC2w with Rds and running the system.`

**Please help me anymore.it immediate.Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install `mysql command line client`. The info is already there in the screenshot. You need to install `mysql-client-core-5.5` or `mysql-client-core-5.6` depending on your RDS MySQl version.

So, you may want to run something like below to install these packages:

```
# apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5
```

Comment: can you please help me another issue regarding about AWS system run with Rds mysql system. i will post this question with in 1/2hrs.Please help on this

Comment: Hi  please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681547/mysql-connection-is-not-working-on-aws-ec2/

Comment: i need some your help

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a RDS instance, you can connect to that instance using tool like, SQLYog. From where you can connect to RDS mysql server.

Comment: but i need to connect ec2 system with rds

Comment: try to refer to elastic ip if it helps out