# Why saturation=0 is not working on my printer for lp or lpr command?

Tags: printing, cups, lpr

I am trying

> lp -o saturation=0 -o /file/path

This is a coloured pdf file and I want a black and white printout of it. Why am I still getting colour print out? Where am I mistaking?

My printer is : HP Deskjet Ink Advantage 1515

Comment: @sudip put more details on it thus other people can check this issue. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678956/is-need-install-mysql-on-aws-ec2-if-i-am-using-aws-rds-as-database-instance as exam.Otherwise your question going to closed.